# jQuery code wont work

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

When I type

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#equals").click(function() {

        $("#water").animate({margin-top: "-200px", opacity: ".65"}, 2000);

    });
});
```

into Dreamweaver the `$("#water")` line gets an error and won't tell me what it is. Please help!

Comment: can you post the associated HTML?

Comment: Some html would be nice :)

Comment: HTML and errors might help us out

Comment: is this only Dreamweaver complaining or does it fail in a browser too ? Perhaps Dreamweaver simply does not know how to deal with such javascript.

Comment: And thanks for getting that song stuck in my head :P

Comment: For starters, `margin-top` should be in quotes... its not a valid json otherwise.

Comment: Are you adding jquery library?

Comment: @TheIronDeveloper that was probably the answer. Post it. Even if it's not the answer it deserves an upvote ;)

Comment: marginTop without the quotes should work as well.

Comment: @ZacharyKniebel Thanks! I'm never certain when to comment vs answer. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is `margin-top` which contains a hypen and it is not wrapped in quotes due to which you must be getting javascript error on the page. Change it to `"margin-top"` then hopefully you should be good.

```
$("#water").animate({"margin-top": "-200px", opacity: ".65"}, 2000);
```

There is a nice article on JavaScript properties and when to omit quotes in a json object. Take a look at it https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/javascript-properties

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what your error is, but what I see is invalid JSON.

`margin-top` should be in quotes... its not a valid json otherwise

One simple check is enter the following into your browser's console:

```
var x = {margin-top: 5};
```

You'll get an error there. :\

Answer (score 1):

**To fix and to make your JavaScript code looks neater**

- Hyphen in the property name confuses the compiler, so wrap that property name with quotes.

Thus, your code then becomes:

```
$('#water').animate({'margin-top': '-200px', 'opacity': .65}, 2000);
```

***PS.*** *I removed my last two suggestions. Please check from the comments in case you're curious.*

Comment: You should remove your second bullet point. Any number passed as a new property value to animate can be passed as a number or string, interchangeably. There is nothing wrong with passing it as a string, and no benefit either way; that bullet point is pure opinion and is not a convention. Even marking it as a "trivial" change isn't really sufficient.

Comment: You should also remove your last bullet point as it is also subjective. It is up to the developers own discretion whether or not they use single or double quotes and both have advantages and disadvantages. It is the developer's own conventions that dictate which they use and their own style the types of things they implement that govern which has more advantages to them, and thus which they should "usually" use.

Comment: @ZacharyKniebel I agree with your arguments. However, the last bullet was just a suggested coding guideline by *airbnb*. The key purpose is to make JS string less confusing with HTML when combining between the two. However, it's not a convention. You're absolutely correct.

Comment: I hear you on the quotes, but still...I'm not going to attack anyone's corporate/team/personal conventions, but that's all that is: a localized convention. It's not like we're talking about using the variable name `$this` for `$(this)` or even prepending the `$` onto the name of any variable holding a jQuery object. The quote conventions are just for smaller units so that they can be consistent. This means that the OP's company may have their own convention or may not have any at all. It's another "trivial" change that really shouldn't be made unless their own conventions require it.

Comment: @ZacharyKniebel Your explanation is really clear and straightforward. I like this style of discussion where people interchange their knowledge and opinion. It's constructive :)

Comment: I agree ;) It's what SO is here for :)